# Проблема с форматирование строк в pdf таблице

Tags: python, matplotlib

У меня есть небольшая база данных в которую я собираю покупки.
Я хотел бы их сохранять в pdf файле, но если встречаются длинные имена товаров, то код который я написал, работает не совсем так как нужно. Текст становится очень маленький.

Для создания таблицы я использую matplotlib

Код который у меня есть.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data_2 = [['2021-06-01', 'шоколадка', 14.05],
          ['2021-06-03', 'вафли', 55.0],
          ['2021-06-06', 'Лук зеленый свежий', 25.46],
          ['2021-06-06', 'Помидоры', 30.65],
          ['2021-06-06', 'Хлеб Хлебодар', 33.11],
          ['2021-06-06', 'Хлебушек Домашний', 33.84], ]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 2))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.axis('off')
ax.set_aspect(.1)
rows = list(range(1, 7))
cols = ["Дата", "Имя товара", "Цена"]
table = ax.table(cellText=data_2, colLabels=cols, rowLabels=rows, loc='upper center', cellLoc='center')
table.auto_set_font_size(True)
table.scale(1.5, 15.)
plt.savefig("test.pdf", bbox_inches='tight', facecolor='#a58de0')
```

Этот код дает результат, который я хочу[image: pdf файл]

Данные, которые вызывают проблемы

```
data = [['2021-06-03', 'вафли', 55.0],
        ['2021-06-06', 'Лук зеленый свежий', 25.46],
        ['2021-06-06', 'Помидоры', 30.65],
        ['2021-06-06',
         'Батончик злаковый Fitness с молочным шоколадом и карамелью обогащенный витаминами и минеральными веществами 5 г',
         64.12],
        ['2021-06-06', 'Хлеб Хлебодар Ржаное чудо с клюквой 250 г', 33.11],
        ['2021-06-06', 'Хлебушек Домашний формовой пшенично-ржаной бездрожжевой 330 г', 33.84], ]
```

Что в итоге дает мне очень маленький текст[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В [интернетах пишут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43278040/wrap-text-in-matplotlib-table), что `matplotlib` не умеет переносить текст в ячейках таблиц. Поэтому рекомендуют либо внучную вставить разрыв строки `\n` в строку, либо использовать что-нибудь другое. Например, https://www.reportlab.com/opensource/

Comment: @PakUula Спасибо, с переносами строки стало все отлично. Можно как либо ваш ответ отметить как решение?

Comment: спасибо. Перенёс комментарий в ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В [интернетах пишут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43278040/wrap-text-in-matplotlib-table), что matplotlib не умеет переносить текст в ячейках таблиц. Поэтому рекомендуют либо вручную вставить разрыв строки `\n` в строку, либо использовать что-нибудь другое. Например, [reportlab.com/opensource](https://www.reportlab.com/opensource/)